# How to use $\gtrsim$ in integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

Notation: Let $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ be two real non-negative sequences such that $y_n\neq 0$ for sufficiently large $n$, then $x_n \lesssim y_n$ if $\exists C>0$ such that  $x_n\leq C y_n$ for sufficiently large $n$.

In a paper I am reading it states that
$$
\int_1^2 \exp\left(-\xi\right) \left(\frac{\xi}{R_n^2+2\xi }\right)^{b-1/2}\left(\frac{1}{R_n^2+2\xi }\right)^{a_n+1/2}d\xi\gtrsim (R_n^2+2)^{-b+\frac{1}{2}}(R_n^2+4)^{-a_n-\frac{1}{2}}
$$

where $a_n\rightarrow 0, b>1$ and $R_n$ is nondecreasing.

Why is this true? Do I just substitute $\xi=2$ in the integral?

Comment: I think you just need to use your notation... however I am not sure where the $4$ comes from..?

Comment: @user3911153, I am not sure about the $4$ too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $R_n^2+2\leq R_n^2+2\xi\leq R_n^2+4$ you have, as  $-a_n-\frac12<0$,
$$(R_n^2+2\xi)^{-a_n-\frac12}\geq (R_n^2+4)^{-a_n-\frac12}$$ .
Also, the function $\xi\longmapsto \frac\xi{R_n^2+2\xi}$ is increasing, so it achieves its minimum at $\xi=1$. That is, together with the fact that $b-\frac12>0$,
$$\left[\frac\xi{R_n^2+2\xi}\right]^{-b+\frac12}\geq (R_n^2+2)^{-b+\frac12}.$$

Then
\begin{align}
\int_1^2\!\!\! e^{-\xi} \left[\frac{\xi}{R_n^2+2\xi }\right]^{b-1/2}\left[\frac{1}{R_n^2+2\xi }\right]^{a_n+1/2}\!\!d\xi
&\geq (R_n^2+2)^{-b+\frac{1}{2}}(R_n^2+4)^{-a_n-\frac{1}{2}}\!\int_1^2\! e^{-\xi} \xi^{b-1/2}d\xi\\[0.3cm]
&\geq(R_n^2+2)^{-b+\frac{1}{2}}(R_n^2+4)^{-a_n-\frac{1}{2}}\!\int_1^2 \!e^{-\xi}d\xi\\[0.3cm]
&=c\,(R_n^2+2)^{-b+\frac{1}{2}}(R_n^2+4)^{-a_n-\frac{1}{2}}\\[0.3cm]
\end{align}
where
$$
c=\int_1^2 e^{-\xi}\,d\xi.
$$

Comment: how did you get from the second to third integral?

Comment: It's an inequality. Just the fact that $\xi\geq1$ and $b-\frac12>0$. Or you can completely remove that line and take $c$ to be $\int_1^2e^{-\xi}\xi^{b-\frac12}\,d\xi$ instead.

Comment: Oh thank you. Shouldn't the first inequality be $(R_n^2+2\xi)^{-b+\frac12}\leq (R_n^2+2)^{-b+\frac12}$ because $(R_n^2+2\xi)\geq (R_n^2+2)$?

Comment: Yes , you are right. It's a bit more subtle, then. I'll come back to this a little later.

Comment: Is it possible to use $\frac{R_n^2+2\xi }{\xi}\leq R_n^2+2$ instead?

Comment: No, because the exponent is negative.

Comment: Yes, so we get $\left(\frac{R_n^2+2\xi }{\xi}\right)^{-b+1/2}\geq (R_n^2+2)^{-b+1/2}$... I think it works

Comment: Yes, you are totally right.